# Can custom Tokens for pledges be created?

Tags: custom-fields, tokens

I need to include the amount pledged and the amount they need to pay (which are different values) within an email I'm sending from CiviMail to let our pledgers know when/how to pay and how much. This data is available under each contact, but I can't see anyway to add a new token so I can insert the necessary merge fields into my email and they aren't currently showing in the drop down list. Is this possible?

Comment: hi sarah - if you need to create some new tokens then this might be a good place to look at adding them to https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken

Answer (score 0):

seems we have done work to create such a new token but it has not yet been contributed back to the civitoken extension. would you be able to help fund this to happen.

Also a colleague reminded me we have done some work so that you can generate a checksum with a link that will take the person through to a contribution page with the Pledge ID and Amount in the url so the form loads with the right data. Doesn't deal with your first request, but could be really useful if the reason for sending them the 'amount' is because you want them to pay, and to have an easy online way of paying that actually connects the payment to the relevant pledge

Comment: sorry just checked and the latter also has not been contributed back to the community yet afaik so may take a bit of work to get this publishable

Answer (score 0):

There is a CiviCRM hook that allows the development of additional tokens, so it is certainly possible. Do I assume correctly that you are not developing yourself? If so, you could either provide some funding to add this to the civitoken extension as @petednz suggested, or you can fund an expert near you (or one you already are in contact with) to develop this for you.